# struggling to fix: "ReferenceError: Property 'ReadableStream' doesn't exist"

Tags: javascript, react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk

I am working on a project with AWS-SDK V3, Cognito and AWS. I am struggling to setup basic functions, and keep getting errors like: ReferenceError: Property 'ReadableStream' doesn't exist. I can't find anything online, and I am questioning if this is even a good authentication approach for a scalable react native application. Has anyone dealt with this issue or know how to fix it? I am simply trying to use an "initiateauthcommand" from the V3 library, but clearly there are some compatability issues.

For context, I am using an EXPO development environment for my react native ios mobile app.

I tried using metro bundler fixes, doing pollyfilling, none of it worked. I am stumped.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure you've added the required polyfills for ReadableStream in your React Native Expo project. Try these imports:

```
import 'react-native-get-random-values';
import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto';
import { ReadableStream } from 'web-streams-polyfill/ponyfill';
globalThis.ReadableStream = ReadableStream;
```

Install necessary packages:

```
npm install react-native-get-random-values react-native-url-polyfill web-streams-polyfill
```

If the issue persists, check for library updates and ensure compatibility with React Native. Consider exploring other authentication options based on your project needs.

Comment: This indeed resolves the problem. I ran into another problem that needed a similar fix ( Cannot read property 'apply' of 'undefined' ) that was resolved by "import '@aws-sdk/util-endpoints';". I hope to find an overall fix, because having to deal with these errors when trying to use the AWS SDK v3 in React Native is unmaintainable.

Comment: in a bare-bones react-native project, import { ReadableStream } from 'web-streams-polyfill' did the trick. 'web-streams-polyfill/ponyfill' could not be found in node modules (v4.0.0)